Не достается информация из JSON
Не достается данные из JSON. Все время выходит эта ошибка. Причем даже в скачанных чужих репозиториях. Как ее пофиксить и достать данные?

Это мой data.json файл
[
    {
        "name": "Аэробика",
        "time": "10 am",
        "maxCountParticipants": 30,
        "currentCountParticipants": 25
    },
    {
        "name": "Плавание",
        "time": "12 pm",
        "maxCountParticipants": 20,
        "currentCountParticipants": 12
    },
    {
        "name": "Силовые тренировки",
        "time": "16 pm",
        "maxCountParticipants": 25,
        "currentCountParticipants": 20
    }
]

А это js файл
fetch('data.json')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(jsonData => console.log(jsonData));


По протоку file - fetch запрещен

Я только изучаю и не понимаю таких кратких ответов как ваш. Я понимаю, что какая-то политика CORS запрещает мне извлекать из этого файла. Я не понимаю как это обойти

@bodi простой обход: храните данные в формате .js, к пример файла: export const data = { /* ваши данные */ }

Скорее всего вы написали ваш проект и просто открыли html для запуска. Это - локальный запуск. В таком запуске запрещено читать локальные файлы, даже json. Вам надо запустить ваш проект хотя бы в локальном сервере, тогда будет доступ. Прочитайте про live-server к примеру и как его использовать.

@ΝNL993 Сделал. Не помогло.
